# LINQ DataContext

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am new to LINQ and have to write several LINQ operations within a single method.  I am wondering if they should all refer to a single LinqToSQLClassesDataContext, or whether each operation needs a separate LinqToSQLClassesDataContext?  And if they can use the same LinqToSQLClassesDataContext, is there some operation that needs to be done to reset it before using it for something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have no problem creating one context at the top of your method, and using it throughout your method.  Just make sure you dispose of it when you are done.

After each operation you should call `context.SubmitChanges()` to save any changes back to the database.